# Was $\Sigma x$ used as quantifier?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ho.history-overview, notation

Kurt Gödel in 1931 used $x\Pi a$ where we in contemporary notation would use $(\forall x) A$ or $(x)A$, and $Ex a$ where we would use $(\exists x) A$. I believe that I remember that $\Sigma xA$ has been used with the meaning $\exists x A$. Is my belief correct, and if so by what authors was $\Sigma x$ so used? What, if any, connections are there to Gödel's usage?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#General_formulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_%28logic%29),

- Charles Sanders Peirce used $\Pi_x$, $\Sigma_x$ in 1885;
- Guiseppe Peano used (x), $(\exists x)$ in 1897;
- Gentzen introduced $\forall x$ in 1935;
- $(\forall x)$, $(\exists x)$ became standard in the 1960s.

Comment: Thanks Bjørn! I particularly like Peirce's notation, and will invoke it in the formalized meta language. Do you have a reference?

Comment: $\bigwedge$ for $\forall$ and $\bigvee$ for $\exists$ were used as well at some point.

Comment: Oops! I now see the Wikipedia entry where I gleaned and missed earlier.

Comment: I seem to recall that $\exists x$ appears in Godel's 1935 paper too; maybe that was implicit in your list.

Comment: In Giuseppe Peano, [Studi di logica matematica](http://books.google.it/books/about/Selected_works_of_Giuseppe_Peano.html?id=6upLAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (1896-97) (Engl.trans., page 190) and in the 2nd vol of the [Formulaire](https://archive.org/stream/formulairedemath00pean#page/28/mode/2up) (1897), page 28, we can find $\exists$. But it [seems](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) that the introduction of $(x)$ for the universal quantifier is due to B.Russell, [Mathematical Logic as Based on the Theory of Types](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-2369948/2369948#page/n7/mode/2up) (1908), page 228-

Comment: Is it correct that the Peano universal quantification is just parentheses around the variable, with no other symbol?